# How to Call a Go Program from Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I have a Go program which cannot be rewritten in Common Lisp for efficiency reasons. How can I run it via Common Lisp?

Options so far:

### 1. CFFI

Using the foreign function interface seems to me like the "correct" way to do this. However, the research I did lead directly to a dead end. If this is the winner, what resources are there to learn about how to interface with Go?

### 2. Sockets

Leaving the Go program running all the time while listening on a port would work. If this is the best way, I'll continue trying to make it work.

### 3. Execute System Command

This seems all kinds of wrong.

### 4. Unknown

Or is there an awesome way I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: Option (3) is what I would probably choose at first. But not knowing your requirements, it's unclear why that would be "all kinds of wrong".

Comment: It's not a very well founded sentiment. Bad experiences with PHP left a bad taste in my mouth. It's on the list! Winner?

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit more information in this question: What dead end did you hit with 1? Why does 3 seem wrong to you? What OS/platform is this running on? How long-lived are each of your processes? Will you be calling go just once, or many times? Stuff like that... Also, I slightly question the efficiency statement, unless you mean efficiency of programmer time/effort, which seems more plausible, though... Anyway, I'm willing to take this for granted, but I'm not sure you should. :)

Comment: All excellent questions. I was under the impression that the FFI applied to all languages, not just C. Using shell execution commands is too much of a security hazard. The system is running CentOS and SBCL. Lisp is running as a daemon, Go can go either way if necessary. The Go program will need to be called many times from Lisp and respond when finished. I wrote the same code in both Lisp and Go - it took about the same amount of effor for each (the Lisp is prettier ;) - unoptimized Lisp 65 sec, optimized 13.5 sec - Go 2 sec (literally).

Comment: For those those who stumble upon this searching for a solution to this same problem, the solution that ended up working the best for me was using [run-program](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-external-programs). It isn't part of the ANSI standard, so check your implementation. The hesitance to using it for security reasons did not apply at all to Common Lisp. It won over sockets in favor of removing a potential point of failure and avoiding the need to start more than one service each time the server reboots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do, but 1-3 are all viable options

### 1. CFFI

To get this to work you will need to use FFI on both the go and lisp side.
You will need to extern the appropriate function from Go as C functions, and then call them using cffi from lisp. See https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go on how to extern function in go. In this case you would create a dynamically linkable library (dll or so file) rather than an executable file.

### 2. Sockets (IPC)

The second option is to run your go program as a daemon and use some form of IPC (such as sockets) to communicate between lisp and go. This works well if your program is long running, or if it makes sense to have a server and one or more clients (the server could just as easily be the lisp code as the go code). Sockets in particular are also more flexible, you could write components in other languages or change languges for one component without having to change the others as long as you maintain the same protocol. Also, you could potentially run the components on seperate hardware. However, using sockets may hurt performance.
There are other IPC methods available, such as FIFO files (named pipes), SHM, and message queues, but they are more system dependent than sockets.

### 3. System command (subprocess)

The third way is to start a sub-process. This is a viable option, but it has some caveats. First of all, the behavior of starting a sub process is dependent both on the lisp implementation and the operating system. UIOP smooths out a lot of the details for implementation differences, but some are too great to overcome. In particular, depending on the implementation you may or may not be able to  run a subprocess in parallel. If not you will have to run a seperate command every time you want to communicate with go, which means waiting for the process to start up every time you need it. You also may, or may not be able to send input to the subprocess after starting it.

Another option is to run a command to start a go process, and then communicate with it using sockets or some other IPC, and then running a command to stop the process before closing the lisp program.

Personally, I think that using sockets is the most attractive option, but depending on your needs, one of the other options might be better suited.

Comment: looking back at your question, I should point out that there will be overhead to all of these methods, especially 2 and 3. It may actually be faster to rewrite the go program in lisp than to add an i/o bottleneck (or type conversions  in the case of cffi). Unless your go program does some serious cpu bound computations, like heavy number crunching.

Comment: Sockets it is. The point you made about being able to easily switch out the program on the listening end is interesting. Regarding the Foreign Function Interface, I was under the impression that it could interface with any language; alas. Overhead calls will be negligible compared with the total execution time in this case. Next time, using C typing will probably be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

**CFFI** is to use C from Common Lisp. It's an easy way to get new features without too much hassle as the libraries out there usually are written in C or have a C interface. If you can make a C library from your Go source then you can do this and use the foreign feature from CL.

**Sockets** (or other two way communication bus) are good if the Go program is a service that is supposed to provide something. Eg. an application server to serve http requests. Usually if you only need to use the go program once each run of the CL program this isn't the way to go.

**Subprocess** is best if you can run your application with arguments and get a result that is used in Common Lisp. It's not good if you are going to use the Go program many times as it will have overhead (in which the sockets thing would be best)

**Awesome** way to do this *is to make the whole thing in Common Lisp*. If you choose a implementation that has a good compiler and write it well you might get away with having the application as a CL image. If you need to speed up things you can focus on the slow parts and optimize them og you can use **CFFI** by writing the optimizations in C. There is even a [Inline C for SBCL](https://common-lisp.net/project/cinline/) where you can just write C where you want to optimize in CL and you don't need to write the optimizations in their own file and compile and link separately.